# WolframAlpha gives small imaginary part for real integral $\int_0^\infty \log(1 - 2xe^{-x} - e^{-2x})\,dx$

Tags: numerical-integration, symbolic

Putting the integral $$\int_0^\infty \log(1 - 2xe^{-x} - e^{-2x})\,dx$$ into [Wolfram|Alpha gives](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+log%281+-+2*x*exp%28-x%29+-+exp%28-2x%29%29%2C+x+%3D+0%2C+infinity) `integral_0^∞ log(1 - e^(-2 x) - 2 e^(-x) x) dx = -6.89753 + 3.19343×10^-7 i`

Two questions:

1. Which numerical algorithm does it use that produces this small imaginary part?
2. Is there a chance for a symbolic solution for this integral?

Comment: Increase `WorkingPrecision ` :  `NIntegrate[Log[1 - 2 x Exp[-x] - Exp[-2 x]], {x, 0, Infinity}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 10] (*-6.897539442*)`

Comment: @heiner - questions solely about Wolfram|Alpha are not appropriate for this site. Suggest that you check with the [`Wolfram Community`](https://community.wolfram.com)